# Render a Video inside an SVG element to ByPass Object-Fit Polyfills for Video Elements

Tags: html, video, svg, aspect-ratio

I've seen a way of using SVG to center an `<image>` in the same way `object-fit` works. Because the `<image>` is part of an `<svg>` tag it means browser support is a whole lot better, and it removes the need for a polyfill for certain browsers. Basically it centers the image using `xMidYmid` in the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute and then you add the `slice` value as part of this attribute to make the image cover the container. It's brilliant.

I would like to use this method on `<video>` elements, because, for whatever reason, Microsoft have decided not to implement `object-fit` on video or canvas elements (?).  I'm hopeful the technique will transfer OK, the problem I'm having is `<video>` elements only render inside an SVG tag when they are within a ` tag, because there is no native svg video element, like there is with .

Does anyone know how to make the inner `<foreignObject>` element and its child `<video>` element inherit the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute values from the `<svg>` tag? Or indeed how to set these attributes directly on the `<foreignObject>` tag?

I'd love it if there is a way of doing this.

**Codepen**

Here is a Codepen that shows the `<image>` and `<video>` tags and you can see the problem I have on the video one.  https://codepen.io/pauljohnknight/pen/GyXLrK

HTML / SVG

```
<!-- THIS IS THE IMAGE THAT WORKS OK-->
<svg width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 579 375" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9674/photo-1501366062246-723b4d3e4eb6.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
</svg>

<!-- THIS IS THE VIDEO THAT ISN'T PlAYING BALL -->
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 579 375" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
    <video autoplay loop x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400">
    <source src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bakerboxvideos/handwriting2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</foreignObject>

</svg>
```

CSS

```
body {
display: flex;
padding: 100px;
justify-content: center;
}

svg {
margin: 20px;
border: 5px solid;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: If you want non-SVG element content to display in SVG there's no alternative to foreignObject.

Comment: That's what I thought might be the case.  An `<img>` tag isn't  an SVG element though? Although I accept that might be the one exception.  I guess I need to try and work out how to get the `<foreignObject>` tag to adopt the preserveAspectRatio then. If that is possible.

Comment: An <image> tag is an SVG element, the equivalent html tag is <img>. I'm not sure I see what point you're trying to make about <img> as it won't display if you include it directly in SVG unless it's a child of a <foreignObject> tag.

Comment: Sorry, I've amended the question I meant `<image>`, I see why the first example works now.  Is there no way of getting the `<foreignObject>` tag to inherit the perserveAspectRatio values so they can be applied to the child `video` element?